# Let $U, W$ be subspaces of finite dimensional Vector Space $V$ over $K$ with $\dim U + \dim W > \dim V$. Show that $U \cap W \neq$ {$0$}.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

Let $U, W$ be subspaces of  finite dimensional Vector Space $V$ over $K$ with $\dim U + \dim W > \dim V$. Show that $U \cap W \neq$ {$0$}.

---

The first thing I thought about is this formula 
$$\dim(U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim (U \cap W)$$

We know $\dim(U+W) \leq \dim V$ because $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$, and the dimension of a subspace is always less than or equal to the dimension of the space they belong to.

Using those two formulas, we have
$$\dim V \geq \dim(U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim (U \cap W)$$

If we rearrange, we have
$$\dim (U \cap W) \geq \dim U + \dim W - \dim (V)$$

We are given that
$$\dim U + \dim W > \dim V$$
so we know
$$\dim U + \dim W - \dim (V) > 0$$
so we have
$$\dim (U \cap W) \geq \dim U + \dim W - \dim (V) > 0$$
which implies $U \cap W \neq$ {$0$}.

Is this correct or did I do something wrong or forgot something ?

Comment: it works........

Comment: I think this is  correct, and the use of Grassman formula seems to be the easier way to prove this

Comment: You write dim$(U +W)$ = dim$U$ + dim$W$ - dim$V$ - are you sure about that? (This is about writing correct mathematics rather than the logic of your argument.)

Comment: @Uzai is right. You need to change "$\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim V$" to "$\dim U+\dim W-\dim V$" in your proof.

Comment: @Uzai I'm a bit confused, why can't we write $\dim (U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim V$ ?

Comment: @wengen Because it isn't true: say $V$ is three-dimensional, $U$ and $W$ are both two-dimensional (two planes in 3D space). If that equation was true, then $U+W$ would have dimension $2 + 2 - 3 = 1$: but it includes $U$ as a subspace so it must have dimension $\geq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You can also use proof by contradiction.

Suppose, for a contradiction, that $U\cap W=\{0\}$. Then $\dim(U\cap W)=0$. Since $\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)$, we have $\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W$. We know that $\dim V\geq\dim(U+W)$, because $U+W$ is a subspace of $V$. It follows that $\dim V\geq\dim U+\dim W$, which contradicts our assumption that $\dim V<\dim U+\dim W$. This completes the proof.